# Spring mvc3 application test environment setup

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I am working under a spring mvc3 application.

And I meet some problem when I want to do some unit test for the Dao component.

This is my application structure in eclipse:

```
application
    build
        classes
    src
        org.....
    res
        jdbc.properties
        log4j.properties
    www
        resources
            css
            js
        WEB-INF
            mybatis
                config.xml
            view
            spring
                servlet-context.xml
                spring-contex.xml
                spring-dao.xml
            web.xml
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<!-- web related config omitted -->
    <import resource="spring-context.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-dao.xml" />
```

spring-context.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">.......</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis/config.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

spring-dao.xml:

```
<bean id="postDao" class="com.king.dao.PostDao" />
```

And this is my PostDao class:

```
public class PostDao extends SqlSessionDaoSupport{
    public Post query(int id) {
        return getSqlSession().selectOne("com.king.model.PostMapper.selectById", id);
    }
}
```

The above configuration works well in the servlet container.

However when I want to test the PostDao without in the servlet environment,I meet some problems.

I tried this:

```
public static main(String[] args){
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("E:/application/www/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml");
    PostDao pd = (PostDao) ctx.getBean("postDao");
    Post p = pd.query(9);
}
```

Then I get the error, the "mybatis/config.xml" can not be founded.

I know this is caused by the different running environment.

In servlet context,spring will find the "/WEB-INF/mybatis/config.xml",but when in a java application,it can not find it.

So I wonder how can I make my testing work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean unit or integration testing? If so, I'd recommend using the Spring Test module - it allows you to define a specific test context where you can provide real or mocked implementations of the relevant beans. It integrates well with JUnit and provides a lot of the scaffolding you need to successfully run tests within a Spring environment.